# No shares accepted when connected to LAN farm node

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, json-rpc

I was mining for about 30 hours and nothing showed up at the pool.  They never saw me connected.

I was running geth on Ubuntu 16.04 and and mining on my windows PC connecting to geth on ubuntu box with -F.

The entire time, I was seeing messages that said "Commit new mining work", but I have nothing to show for it?

Are there logs I can look at?  Or is there nothing I can do?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you were solo mining, and not connected to any pool.
geth will sync the blockchain and allow you to solo mine.
what mining software were you using and what do you have in the config file?